# Probability Density Distribution Exercise

Tags: probability

So here I have 2 exercises to which I have solutions of mine, but wonder if they are correct, so they are as follows:

[image]

My solutions are:

> **1)** I used this formula;
>
> E(X) = x$_1$p(x$_1$) + x$_2$p(x$_2$) + ... x$_n$p(x$_n$)
>
> So it looks like this:
>
> E(X) = (0 $\times$ 0.18) + (1 $\times$ 0.28) + (2 $\times$ 0.25) + (3 $\times$ 0.18) + (4 $\times$ 0.06) + (5 $\times$ 0.04) + (6 $\times$ 0.01) = 0 + 0.28 + 0.5 + 0.54 + 0.24 + 0.2 + 0.06 = 1.82
>
> So since the solution is 1.82 does that mean that it is going to be either 1 or 2 failures but more likely 2 than 1?
>
> **2)** Same formula as before, thus the result is:
>
> E(X) = (0 $\times$ 0.237) + (1 $\times$ 0.396) + (2 $\times$ 0.264) + (3 $\times$ 0.088) + (4 $\times$ 0.014) + (5 $\times$ 0.001) = 0 + 0.396 + 0.528 + 0.264 + 0.056 + 0.005 = 1.249
>
> So the answer is either 1 or 2, most likely 1 program compiles in a day.

Are those correct? Should I state that either 1 or 2nd but most likely X than Y (depending on the value)?

Thank you in advance!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are correct, but your interpretation of the values is not.

The expected value of a random variable is not, in general, an outcome of that variable.  Suppose I give you a fair six-sided die.  You would calculate the expected value of a roll of the die as $(1+2+3+4+5+6)/6 = 3.5$, but it is obvious that the die can never show a result of 3.5.  Rather, 3.5 represents in some sense the average value of many repeated outcomes of the random process of rolling the die; that is to say, if you rolled the die 100 times, took the sum of all the rolls you observed, and divided by the number of times you rolled it, then the result would be close to 3.5.

In the same vein, an expected value of 1.82 failures does not mean the computer fails 1.82 times in a week.  At any given point in time, the computer has failed or it has not--it cannot fail a fractional number of times.  1.82 simply represents an expectation of the average number of times it will fail in a week, based on the given probability distribution of observing a certain number of failures in that period.